# Create a nested JSON with filtered ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I have a requirement to create a nested JSON data with 3 levels of active record objects as follows:

- Contact has many chantiers
- Chantiers has many Photos

> ```
>   render :json => contact.as_json(include: { 
>                                     chantier: { include: { 
>                                         photo: { only: [:url, :titre, :commentaires, :sharing]} }, 
>                                     only: [:id, :nom_chantier]}
>                                 }, only: [:id, :type, :email, :firstname, :lastname])
> ```

Currently, the JSON all the records that are associated with the Contact. However I need to restrict the 3 level object **Photo** to display only those records with the "sharing" field equal to true.

Something like : Photo.where(sharing: true) instead of all Photos

Can anyone please advise on how to achieve that?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is by creating an association that is filtered to only show "shared photos", and then including that in your JSON output. In your `Contact` model, add the following:

```
# You probably have something like this already:
has_many :photos

# Below is what you need to add

# Rails 4
has_many :shared_photos, -> { where(shared: true) }, source: :photos

# Rails 3
has_many :shared_photos, conditions: lambda { where(shared: true) }, source: :photos
```

Once you've set up the conditional association, you can use it in an `as_json` call the same way you normally include associations, like so:

```
render :json => contact.as_json(include: :shared_photos)
```